# Looking for multiple tags with *

Tags: support

When I'm logged in and I search for [`[tikz*]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz*) I obtain as result `[tikz-pgf] or [tikz-styles] or [tikz-arrows] or [tikz-trees] or [tikz-external] or [tikz-cd] or [tikz-qtree] or [tikz-matrix] or [tikz-3dplot] or [tikzposter] or [tikz-node] or [tikz-graphs] or [tikzmark] or [tikz-pic] or [tikz-feynman] or [tikz-uml] or [tikz-shape] or [tikz-circuit-lib] or [tikz-graphdrawing] or [tikzscale]`.

But when I'm not logged in and I search for the same [`[tikz*]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz*) I obtain as result only `[tikz-pgf] or [tikz-styles] or [tikz-arrows]`.

Any idea why this difference ?

**Edit:** I tried to search for 4 tags when logged off, and my query was cut down to 3 tags. So probably this is related to maximal number of tags that non logged user can use in a query.

Comment: Is the same sorting used in both cases? E.g. "frequent" vs. "active" etc.?

Comment: @samcarter The sort order has nothing to do with the search filter. In the first case (when logged in) it is searching for 20 tags, and in the second case it is searching for 3 tags (with the same shortcut query).

Comment: Probably to reduce the unregistered search load to avoid DDoS-like attacks